# Returning reference to nested class

Tags: java, inner-classes, nested-class, return-type

When you have a nested class such as this

```
public class OuterClass {

    public class InnerClass {

    }
}
```

and you want to have a method that returns reference to the inner class, whitch of the following is better to do?

```
public class OuterClass {

    public InnerClass someMethod() {

    }

    public class InnerClass {

    }
}
```

or

```
public class OuterClass {

    public OuterClass.InnerClass someMethod() {

    }

    public class InnerClass {

    }
}
```

Edit:

my reason for asking is because when ever I create a method in eclipse that returns say a map entry the return type generated by eclipse is always shown as

```
Map.Entry<SomeObject, SomeObject>
```

and I wonder if there is a reason behind it

Comment: That's basically the same, the explicit `OuterClass.` can be omitted.

Comment: What's your intent? If I defined one class within another, I would never want to expose it.

Comment: There are real life example when inner classes are exposed.

Comment: I ask because when ever I create a method that returns Map.Entry<K,V> the generated return type in eclipse is Map.Entry and I wonder if there is a reason behind it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in meaning, but you can access this only this way:

```
 OuterClass.InnerClass innerClass = new OuterClass().someMethod();
```

Explicit `OuterClass` couldn't be ommited in other classes, because method signature is:

```
public OuterClass.InnerClass someMethod();
```